# Discord.py - Asyncio Timeout not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

### Expected output and what my code for it is:

My bot is supposed to send a message, and then check if the user who sent the command reacted on that message with `:arrow_left:`, `:arrow_right:`, or `:wastebasket:` and if they did, it is supposed to change the "page" of the message. That part works fine, but I also want the message to timeout after 7 seconds of inactivity.

```py
        embed = await self.get_member_list(ctx, member, page)

        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        reactions = ["⬅️", "➡️", "️"]
        for x in r:
            await msg.add_reaction(x)
            await asyncio.sleep(.35)

        def check(payload):
            return str(payload.emoji) in reactions

        done = False
        page = 1
        while not done:
            try:
                pending_tasks = [self.bot.wait_for('raw_reaction_add', timeout=7.0, check=check),
                                 self.bot.wait_for('raw_reaction_remove', timeout=7.0, check=check)]

                done_tasks, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(pending_tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

                for task in done_tasks: payload = await task
                user = await commands.MemberConverter().convert(ctx, str(payload.user_id))

            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                done = True
                return
            else:
                if user == ctx.author:
                    if str(payload.emoji) == "️":
                        return await msg.delete(delay=0)
                    if str(payload.emoji) == "⬅️":
                        if page == 1:
                            page = total_pages
                        else:
                            page -= 1
                    if str(payload.emoji) == "➡️":
                        if page == total_pages:
                            page = 1
                        else:
                            page += 1
                    await msg.edit(embed=await self.get_member_list(ctx, member, page)) #
```

However, I am facing the problem "Task exception was never retrieved" after running the code above.

### Actual results:

```py
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-58' coro=<wait_for() done, defined at C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:434> exception=TimeoutError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 501, in wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError()
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

### The problem:

Whenever 7 seconds of inactivity passes and it is supposed to timeout I get an error. I have tried to fix this by running asyncio.gather() but I am unfamiliar with asyncio and I am unsure how to use it properly.

```
done_tasks, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(pending_tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
await asyncio.gather('raw_reaction_add', 'raw_reaction_remove', return_exceptions=True)
```

### I have tried:

- Checking for typos
- Running `except Exception` and `except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError` instead of `except asyncio.TimeoutError`
- Contemplating my sanity
- Reading the asyncio [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait), specifically on asyncio.wait()
- Making sure that my bot has all the permissions and intents it needs in discord
- Using `self.bot.wait_for()` with raw_reaction_add and raw_reaction_remove inside of a tuple instead of `asyncio.wait()`

Comment: Does it work when you use just one event without using `asyncio.wait` ?

Comment: @Ceres yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting rid of the error message by doing this:

First I moved the timeout from `bot.wait_for()` to `asyncio.wait()`

```
pending_tasks = [self.bot.wait_for('raw_reaction_add', check=check),
                 self.bot.wait_for('raw_reaction_remove', check=check)]

                done_tasks, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(pending_tasks, timeout=7.0, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

Then I got the payload from a pop instead of awaiting task

```
payload = done_tasks.pop().result()
```

Now after 7 seconds of inactivity it tries to pop from an empty set and raises a KeyError which I can catch using `except KeyError:`